# Copy files with timestamp into folders and subfolders, which are built in year/month/day in Python

Tags: python

I have a question. I have files in different folders and subfolders. I have created a new file system in a new environment by year, month and day. I want to save the files there, I would like to read the files according to their timestamps and store them automatically in the designated folders. How do you do that best?

Comment: What is the format of the files? Where are your attempts to solve this problem?

Comment: See this link - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

SRC_PATH = './src'
DST_PATH = './dst'

for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(SRC_PATH):
    for filename in filenames:
        src_filepath = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        last_edit = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(src_filepath))

        dst_dirpath = os.path.join(DST_PATH, str(last_edit.year), str(last_edit.month), str(last_edit.day))
        dst_filepath = os.path.join(dst_dirpath, filename)

        os.makedirs(dst_dirpath, exist_ok=True)
        os.rename(src_filepath, dst_filepath)

        print(src_filepath, '->', dst_filepath)
```

It will walk recursively your directory structure and move all files to another directory named by `YEAR/MONTH/DAY` of file modification.

Docs:

- [os.walk()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)
- [os.makedirs()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use datetime to format timestamp to string and then define you folder name

```
from datetime import datetime
ts = 1514101485
folder_name = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y_%m_%d')
```